# Can't install CA certificate on Android 11

Tags: android, certificate, android-11

On preview version of Android 11 I got an error when trying to install CA certificate:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent("android.credentials.INSTALL");
intent.putExtra("name", getCertName());
intent.putExtra("CERT", getCert());
startActivity(intent);
```

The error message is:

> **Can't install CA certificates**
>
> CA certificates can put your privacy at risk and must be installed in
>   Settings.

[image]

I haven't found nothing on **Android documentation** about this change. Any ideas? Any workarounds (except to install it manually from settings)?

**UPDATE (28/4):**

Found a bug in issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151858120

Comment: Starting *KeyChain.createInstallIntent()* on Android 11 beta 1 works fine for me.

Comment: @M66B thanks. Trying KeyChain.createInstallIntent() and choosing a certificate file, we still getting this error. Did you succeed to choose a cert file without error?

Comment: it works fine for me (Pixel 3a XL, Android 11 beta 1)

Comment: @M66B Still getting the issue even on same device with Android 11 Beta. Can you please share your code with me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a tiny note about this in the Android 11 enterprise changelog [here](https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-11#other), which says:

> Note: Apps installed on unmanaged devices or in a device's personal profile can no longer install CA certificates using createInstallIntent(). Instead, users must manually install CA certificates in Settings.

Sounds very much like this is intentional, and you won't be able to get around it on normal unmanaged devices. You'll either need to look into full Android device management, or provide instructions to your users on doing manual setup instead.

Note that registering your app as a normal device admin app is not sufficient either. To use the remaining [DevicePolicyManager.installCaCert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#installCaCert(android.content.ComponentName,%20byte%5B%5D)) API **your app must be the *owner* of the device or profile**.

That means from Android 11+, you can do automatic setup for CA certs used only within separate & isolated work profiles on the device, or for fresh devices that you provision with your app pre-installed, and nothing else.

**If you'd like this behaviour changed, there's an issue you can star & comment on in the Android tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168169729**

Answer (score 55):

I have also face same issue.

## Please follow below steps in android 11 or 11+.

In Android 11, to install a CA certificate, users need to manually:

1. Open Device settings
2. Go to 'Security'
3. Go to 'Encryption & Credentials'
4. Go to 'Install from storage' or 'Install a certificate' (depend on devices)
5. Select 'CA Certificate' from the list of types available
6. Accept a warning alert.
7. Browse to the certificate file on the device and open it
8. Confirm the certificate install

---

## Pixel 6 - Android 14

1. Open Device settings
2. Go to Security and privacy
3. Go to More security and privacy (scroll to the bottom)
4. Go to 'Encryption & Credentials'
5. Go to 'Install from storage' or 'Install a certificate' (depending on the devices)
6. Select 'CA Certificate'
7. tap on 'Install anyway' and verify security (thumb or PIN etc)
8. Select your downloaded certificate (it could be available in the downloaded folder)
9. can see a toast message 'CA certificate installed'.
   Certificate installed in your device now.

---

## On "modern" Samsung phones

it's hidden in Settings -> Biometrics and security -> Other security settings -> Install from device storage -> CA Certificate -> Install Anyway

Comment: I am not sure why this answer was downvoted... I was able to install the CA Certificate with those instructions

Comment: @Feedbacker its ok. ans should be helpful.

Comment: This is helpful Thanks.

Comment: @RWorld much obliged.

Comment: did all of that and it's still not working for apps, (just for chrome)

Comment: saved my life. On "modern" Samsung phones, it's hidden in Settings -> Biometrics and security -> Other security settings -> Install from device storage -> CA Certificate -> Install Anyway.

Comment: Can confirm it also works for OnePlus Nord (had to install as a Wifi certificate). Thanks!

Comment: why does my cert files are grayed out?